# How much will the upcoming election be driven by the government shutdown?

Tags: united-states, election, government-shutdown, senate

My question is, what is the estimate of people who will be voting in a particular way because of the events around the government shutdown and threat of a default on the budget caused by deadlock between the house and senate a year ago? And, if people are swayed who are they and how are they likely to vote now?

Will the budget battles affect the current senate race?

Comment: To answer the title question: The cynic in me wants to say none at all. We're too amnesic to remember what happened before the most recent news cycle, let alone what happened 13 months ago. But I don't have any data to back that up.

Comment: I'd have to agree with you, I am wondering as well if anyone has brought up specific people's actions in attack ads to remind the voters

Comment: Less significant than an ad, so I don't know if you'd count it, but I've seen a meme on FB along the lines of "remember how we had to shut down the national parks in 2013, yet we have money to drop million dollar bombs in Iraq?" Of course, there's a significant selection bias when you collect data from libertarians.

Comment: ...I don't see that as a partisan issue, it does not matter if you are on the left or on the right, it will always be easier to get money for bombs than for parks. And it does not matter if you are on the left or on the right, you can always point the finger at the other side.

Comment: Not sure this is answerable outside of pure speculation.

Comment: kleineg, I was referring to how neither mainstream parties seem at all interested in spending less. ( http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2014/11/01/assuming-gop-does-take-the-senate-dems-have-nothing-to-fear.html) The point of the meme is to mock the feigned frugality, not to say that parks are a better use of funds than bombs. Anyway, this is getting OT. Sorry to derail your question.

Comment: I don't know if this will have an impact on the vote. If one party can successfully blame the other for the shutdown, they might be able to get some votes but I doubt it will be a major issue for most people. Since both parties have their share of responsibilities for it, I don't think there is a winner in this.

Comment: This is answerable in a way, if @kleineg is willing to accept  a demonstration that approval rating bumps as a result of the shutdown were temporary as evidence that it didn't have a long lasting effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shutdown will likely have very little impact on the election.

First and foremost, the shutdown was over a year ago, and voters have a notoriously short memory. The Sandy Hook shootings, Edward Snowden, Benghazi: all are stories that were major political stories in 2013 that received only token mentions throughout the 2014 election.

One way to get a good idea of why and how people are voting is to poll on voter priorities. The [most recent CBS polls](http://www.pollingreport.com/prioriti.htm) found the most important issues for voters are the economy, health care, terrorism, and immigration. The most generous interpretation is that some of the 8% of Americans who name the federal budget as the most important issue were thinking of the shutdown. But the vast majority of voters simply aren't thinking about the shutdown.

As to why the shutdown never emerged as a campaign issue, bringing up the shutdown would have been politically risky. [Polls at the time](http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/poll-major-damage-to-gop-after-shutdown-and-broad-dissatisfaction-with-government/2013/10/21/dae5c062-3a84-11e3-b7ba-503fb5822c3e_story.html) showed a majority of Americans at the time blamed the Republicans. But the shutdown was immediately followed by the botched Obamacare rollout, vindicating the most hardline Republicans who based their support on repealing the law. Neither Democrats nor Republicans had too much to gain by bringing it up.

Finally, there wasn't much of a way to personally tie too many Senate candidates to the shutdown. Of the [eight RealClearPolitics tossup races](http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2014/senate/2014_elections_senate_map.html), only two Republican candidates were in the House at the time: Cory Gardner in Colorado and Bill Cassidy in Louisiana. But there isn't really a way to blame guys like former Senator Scott Brown and businessman David Perdue for a shutdown they literally had nothing to do with.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. -10 for a super-naive "there isn't really a way to blame". There's ALWAYS a way to blame your political opponent for stuff, especially for Democrats thanks to their control of the legacy media. Witness Republicans being blamed for left-wing shooter of Rep. Giffords. Or for not enough Ebola research money. Or for favoritism to Big Banking.

Comment: @DVK Cherry-picking instances of bias is itself bias. Libertarian ultra-cynicism of any grouping of two or more people isn't an improvement over naivety/preliminary respect of political representatives.

Comment: @LateralFractal - I didn't say Republicans don't do that. I said Democrats have an easier time of it since a vast majority of the Western mass media is firmly allied/wedded to them. Getting the narrative out isn't an issue.

Comment: Are we really having a "the media is run by the liberals" debate in comments?

Comment: Hey, you were right on the money!